# Creating nested list comprehension of files starting with specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have a directory with 'sets' of files that start with a state name followed by 4 or 5 digits (typically indicating year). Each 'file set' contains 3 files a **.txt**, a **.png**, and a **.jpg**.

Example of files in directory:

```
California1998_reform_paper.txt 
California1998_reform_paper.pdf
California1998_reform_paper.jpg
California2002_waterdensity_paper.txt
California2002_waterdensity_paper.pdf
California2002_waterdensity_paper.jpg
```

Based on a users input I am trying to write some code that can put each of these file sets into a list of lists. Ultimately I would like to iterate over the list of lists. That said, I am not married to any one data type if a dictionary or something else may be more efficient.

I would like the user to be able to enter either:

- The state name i.e. 'California' - to get all files from California 
  OR
- The state name + year i.e. 'California1998' to get all files from California 1998

```
import os
import regex

directory = #path to directory
input = 'California1998'

# Does input match proper format? If not error.
mm = regex.match('^([a-z]+)([0-9]{4,5})|^([a-z]+)', input)
dir = str(os.listdir(directory))
if mm.group(1):
    state = mm.group(1)
    number = mm.group(2)
    state_num = state + number
    fileset = regex.findall(state_num, dir)
elif mm.group(3):
    state = mm.group(3)
    fileset = regex.findall(state + r'[0-9]{4,5}', dir)
else:
    print('Put some error message here')

# Does input exist? If not error.
if len(fileset) > 0:
    fileset = tuple(set(sorted(fileset)))
else:
    print('Put some error message here')

# Get list of lists
state_num_files = [[file.path
    for file in os.scandir(directory)
    if file.name.startswith(state_num)]
    for state_num in fileset]
return state_num_files
```

Above is the code I have thus far. It first uses `regex.match` to check the input, then `regex.findall` to find all matching state + years. I then create a `sorted()` `set()` from this list, which is converted into a `tuple()` called `fileset`. The last bit of code is a nested list comprehension that produces the list of lists by iterating through all files in the directory and iterating through all the state + years in `fileset`.

It certainly works, but seems repetitive and slower than it needs to be. My goal is to increase efficiency and remove any unnecessary iteration.

Thoughts on improvements:

- Possibly replace each `regex.findall` with a nested list comprehension? and thus remove the `state_num_files` nested comprehension at the end of script?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

## Review

1. Bug on Capitalization

   ```
   mm = regex.match('^([a-z]+)([0-9]{4,5})|^([a-z]+)', input)
   ```

   This does not work for the given use case of *California1998*

   But it can be easily fixed by adjusting the regex to include `[A-Za-z]` capital letters
2. Stop overshadowing!

   You use multiple built-in keywords as variable names ie, `input` `dir` this makes it that the overshadowed functions can no longer be used further in the program
3. `import regex`?

   I think this should be `import re`, since that's what the library is called
4. Unnecesarry operations

   The `sort` and consecutive conversion do nothing at all

   Secondly you loop over the directory twice! This can be avoided by doing it one loop.
5. Don't `print` errors `raise` them

   And make sure the user get's back useful information in the error message this generic message is not very helpful :)

## Alternative

Look into the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module this does what you require,

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("./California1998*")
['./California1998_reform_paper.jpg', './California1998_reform_paper.txt', './California1998_reform_paper.pdf']
```

Comment: Note: `glob` is case-sensitive, unless run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Based on your code and what your were trying to do (and  one suggestion from Ludisposed) here's a attempt where you only scan once the directory where your files are situated:

```py
import re
import pathlib
import os
import collections

directory_of_source_file = pathlib.Path("Input files")
file_set_from_input = 'California1998'

state_name_matcher = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)(\d{4,5})?', re.IGNORECASE)
if state_name_found := state_name_matcher.match(file_set_from_input):
    state_wanted = state_name_found[1]
    set_number = state_name_found[2]
    set_number = '' if set_number is None else set_number

    files_found = directory_of_source_file.glob(f"{state_wanted}{set_number}*")
    files_found_strings = list(map(str, files_found))
    if set_number:
        files_found_formatted = [files_found_strings, ]
    else:
        strict_state_name_matcher = re.compile(rf'{os.sep}{state_wanted}(\d{{4,5}})', re.IGNORECASE)
        documents_collector = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for current_file in files_found_strings:
            if matching_document_found := strict_state_name_matcher.search(current_file):
                current_set_number = matching_document_found[1]
                documents_collector[current_set_number].append(current_file)
        files_found_formatted = list(documents_collector.values())
    for current_file_set in files_found_formatted:
        current_file_set.sort()
    print(files_found_formatted)
else:
    print('Put some error message here')
```

I hope I understood correctly what you were trying to do